# Application.Match (Excel) returning unexpected values

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a string value in column A that may or may not exist, so I am using match type 1 to find the smallest value that does not match. However, the Match function is returning unexpected values depending on the *end* of the lookup array I am giving it.

My code currently looks like:

```
Dim SearchRange as Range
Dim EndRow as Integer
Dim CostCode as String

EndRow = 1118 'Value found in another part of code, no problems here

CostCode="01-420"

Set SearchRange=Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & EndRow)

RowNum = Application.Match(CostCode, SearchRange, 1)

Debug.Print RowNum
```

Cost code 01-420 does not exist in the range, but 01-410 does in row 109. The Match function should be returning this (I think), but it is instead returning 280. That is well beyond many larger string values in column A. If I specify the search range as all of column A, Match returns 128. If I specify the range as Range("A1:A" & sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count) or farther down in column A, I get the correct row number. All 3 of these ranges start in the same place (AFAIK), and the only difference is their end. If Match returns a relative value, why would it change so wildly even when the start of all three ranges is the same?

Also, if I start the range at A3 (A1 and A2 are blank) and end at 1118, Match returns 107 instead of 280. It is finding the right cell and returning the correct relative location, which is somewhat the opposite of the situations above. I get why changing the start of the range would return the row number - the row number of the start of the lookup range, but why would starting two rows farther down with the same range end produce such a different result? Is there a technical explanation of why this happens?

I can change my code to simply search the extent of the used range in column A, but I'd really like to understand why this function behaves this way. I've Googled and looked for a similar problem, but everything I have found has to do with syntax errors or misunderstanding of the return of a relative position. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

ETA: Apparently, I changes to the search range do not actually fix the problem. I have run into a situation where Application.Match will find the right row several times, then revert to a the wrong row several hundred rows down. If anyone has had a similar problem, I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Is your data is column A sorted ascending?

Comment: Yes. They are cost codes in the format ## - #### (spaces around dash added for clarity). There are blank rows in between some, but that seems to have little bearing on whether the expected row is returned.